# How to force class template argument deduction when constructing a class in its own member functions?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider following code:

```
struct A {};

template <typename T> struct B
{
    B(T) {}
    auto foo() {return B(A{});} // error: no matching function for call to 'B<int>::B(A)'
};

auto foo() {return B(A{});} // compiles

int main()
{
    foo();
    B b(0);
    b.foo();
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](https://godbolt.org/g/f1sRuk)</kbd>

I understand why `B::foo()` doesn't compile: Inside of `struct B<T>`, `B` (as an injected-class-name) means `B<T>` unless it's explicitly used as a template. Which in this case prevents class template argument deduction.

Let's say I can't do `auto foo() {return B<A>(A{});}` since my actual code relies on slightly elaborate user-provided deduction guides.

The question is: How do I force class template argument deduction when constructing `B` inside of `B::foo`?

<sub>I hope I'm not missing something obvious.</sub>

Comment: `::B(A{})`? ---

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You qualify it so that it's not the injected-class-name.

```
auto foo() {return ::B(A{});}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a function to do the type deduction for you.

```
template <typename T> B<T> make_b(T t) { return B<T>(t); }
```

and use

```
auto foo() {return make_b(A{});}
```